# How to fit and center css family tree inside a div with zoom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

Need help! Is it possible to center this network tree http://bvusolutions.com/tree2.html after loading the page? I would also like to fit this inside a 960px width div to avoid scrolling and have zoom function.

Every time I add another list or level the page gets larger.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

add  `width:50%`  to `.tree ul` and for `.tree li:only-child` add css `width:960px` for having all tree in 960 bu be aware of that it gets a little messy.
but I have no idea how can you zoom this tree.